# ASP MVC RedirectToAction Until Async Process Finishes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Action method in my controller that continues to redirect back to itself until some process is finished. Much like this:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id)
        {
          var result = await GetAsyncData(id);
          if(!result.processed)
          {
             return RedirectToAction("Index","Controller", new {id=id});
          }

        }
```

Everything works as expected, as soon as result.processed is true the redirect no longer occurs. My only concern is with resource handling. Would this code continue to execute if result.processed is always false, even if the user closes the browser.

Comment: Why would you write an async redirect loop which effectively is the same as writing a non-async function?

Answer (score 0):

If it was always false, you would eventually get an `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)`. Note that this could also occur if your `GetAsyncData` lasts too long. I also don't see why you would write an `async` method that would wait for its finish while redirecting.